# Extracting certain records

Tags: sql, mysql

The purpose of this SQL query would be to extract the record 10192 only, because the `end_time` is both in the past and its foreign counterpart in the Node table still has the `status` 1. I don't want to select the record 10111 because it hasn't expired.

I've just finished writing this SQL query, it works! Although I'm sure it can be written better and I'm interested to here what you have to say.

```
SELECT MAX(l.id) AS highestID, l.nid, n.status
                        FROM mbl AS l
                        INNER JOIN node AS n
                        ON l.nid = n.nid
                        WHERE n.status = 1
                        AND (   SELECT end_time 
                                FROM mbl
                                WHERE id = (    SELECT MAX(id) 
                                                FROM mbl
                                                WHERE nid = l.nid
                                                GROUP BY nid
                                            )
                            ) <= NOW()
                        GROUP BY l.nid
```

#### Mlb table data:

> ```
> id  | nid | start_time | end_time
>
> 105 | 5 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00 | 24/07/2014 01:00:00
>
> 589 | 52 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00 | 31/07/2015 01:32:00
>
> 10108 | 874 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00 | 24/07/2014 01:00:00
>
> 10111 | 874 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00 | 24/07/2015 01:00:00 
>
> 10156 | 967 | 20/07/2012 01:00:00 | 24/07/2013 01:00:00
>
> 10161 | 967 | 20/07/2013 01:00:00 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00
>
> 10192 | 967 | 20/07/2014 01:00:00 | 24/07/2014 01:00:00
> ```

#### Node table data:

> ```
> nid  | status
>
> 5 | 0
>
> 52 | 1
>
> 874 | 1
>
> 967 | 1
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: And the results you _want_ are?  What does this actually tell you?  What is `id` referencing?  Remember, auto-generated ids are essentially a shortcut/convenience; you're almost always going to have some collection of data that functions as a unique value anyways (...which might be temporal or otherwise updateable, so they're **really handy**, but in most cases are essentially derived connectors).  Are you trying to get the most recently inserted row (id tricks are hacky for this)?  The most recently _completed_ row (max `end_time` in the past)?  The most recently started row?  Etc...

Comment: I want the most recent row where an `end_time` is in the past and the `status` is 1 in the Node table.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's go over some problems in your original query:

```
SELECT MAX(l.id) AS highestID, l.nid, n.status
..............
GROUP BY l.nid
```

... if there's more than one `n.status` for a given `l.nid`, you get a "random" row, decided by the optimizer (and not controllable by you).  I'm presuming that you only have one row here (we'll exploit this in a bit).

```
(SELECT end_time 
 FROM mbl
 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM mbl
             WHERE nid = l.nid
             GROUP BY nid)) <= NOW()
```

I'm presuming that `id` is still some sort of autogenerated value.  The problem is, outside of some *very* specific contexts, the only thing a db-generated id should be used for is its **uniqueness**.  Especially in situations where rows may be updated, max/min/ordering by ids rapidly becomes irrelevant.  You seem to be attempting to make sure the most-recently-added row has an `end_time` value in the past - if you have some sort of `inserted_at` or similar timestamp, that would be a better column to use.  It would also be helpful to know why you're looking for the greatest id in this case.  (However, as I don't know the other columns in you table, I'm stuck with it for the moment).

It turns out that your statement can be reduced to this:

```
SELECT Most_Recent.highestId, Most_Recent.nid, Node.status
FROM (SELECT nid, MAX(id) AS highestId
      FROM Mbl
      GROUP BY nid) Most_Recent
JOIN Node
  ON Node.nid = Most_Recent.nid
JOIN Mbl
  ON Mbl.nid = Most_Recent.nid
     AND Mbl.id = Most_Recent.highestId
     AND Mbl.end_time <= NOW()
```

.... which not only eliminates a table reference, but your original version had issues with potential RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row)/Cartesian product plans.  Note that we're still required to join to `Mbl` twice, with the second time being solely to make sure that the most-recent row *also* has an `end_time` value in the past (this can't be done in the subquery, because that would collect the most-recent-id of rows with `end_time` in the past)

Comment: The Mbl table has the columns `id`, `nid`, `start_time` and `end_time`. The Mbl table may have multiple rows with the same `nid` but they may have expired (the `end_time` is in the past). I'm joining the Node table to access the `status` column because I'm only interested in the rows with a `status` of 1. I don't have an `inserted_at` column in any of my tables.

Comment: @thebubbles - then perhaps we should get some sample starting data and desired results?  I have a feeling your query isn't matching your expectations, or what you really want/need.  For instance, you could add `AND Node.status = 1` as a condition to the join...

Comment: I've added more detail to my question.

Answer (score 4):

First thing's first. The indentation is all jacked up. There's not really a standard for formatting SQL, but as a rule of thumb, `Select`, `From`, and `Where` for any (sub)query should be at the same indentation level.

```
SELECT MAX(l.id) AS highestID, l.nid, n.status
FROM mbl AS l
INNER JOIN node AS n
    ON l.nid = n.nid
WHERE n.status = 1
    AND (
        SELECT end_time 
        FROM mbl
        WHERE id = (
                SELECT MAX(id) 
                FROM mbl
                WHERE nid = l.nid
                GROUP BY nid
                )
        ) <= NOW()
GROUP BY l.nid
```

Comment: Thanks, I just copied and pasted it from my code. It's cleaned up as per your answer!

Comment: And that's exactly the right thing to do here @thebubbles. We want to see your real code. We make bad code better and good code great. =)

Comment: `FROM`, `WHERE`, and `GROUP BY` should definitely be at the same indentation level. Personally, I would choose to indent `INNER JOIN` relative to that, and outdent `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

**Aliases**

This may seem like nitpicking, but since you already got two good answers, I figured I would point out this only.

```
FROM mbl AS l
INNER JOIN node AS n
```

`l` and `n` mean nothing of themselves. Think of Mr. Maintainer looking back at your script, scratching his head. It may not seem like a big deal in this small of a query, but I have seen this sort of notation used in large scripts and it becomes **very** confusing. With these table names being only 3-4 letters long, I don't think an alias is even relevant.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I've altered a few things in the SQL to preserve privacy of the project it's being used in. The original naming conventions may allow someone to match it to the project it's being used on.